# Template Class: error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

Tags: c++, class, templates, header

I'm having this errors in the code:

- error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
- see reference to class template instantiation 'HashTable' being compiled
- error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
- error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'

Error is found in this line in private functions:

```
vector<HashEntry> array;
```

---

```
    #ifndef _HASHTABLE_H
    #define _HASHTABLE_H
    #include <vector>

    enum EntryType { ACTIVE, EMPTY, DELETED };

    Template <class HashedObj>
    struct HashEntry
    {
    HashedObj element;
    EntryType info;
    HashEntry( const HashedObj & e = HashedObj( ), EntryType i = EMPTY )
    : element( e ), info( i ) { }
    };

    template <class HashedObj>
    class HashTable
    {

    private:
    vector<HashEntry> array;
    int currentSize;
    const HashedObj ITEM_NOT_FOUND;
    bool isActive( int currentPos ) const;
    int findPos( const HashedObj & x ) const;

    public: 
    explicit HashTable( const HashedObj & notFound, int size = 101 );
    HashTable( const HashTable & rhs )
    : ITEM_NOT_FOUND( rhs.ITEM_NOT_FOUND ),
    array( rhs.array ), currentSize( rhs.currentSize ) { }


    const HashedObj & find( const HashedObj & x ) const;
    void makeEmpty( );
    void insert( const HashedObj & x );
    void remove( const HashedObj & x );
    const HashTable & operator=( const HashTable & rhs );

     };
    #endif
```

How can I fix this error C4430?

Comment: You need to specify a type for `HashEntry` as you declared it as a template: `std::vector<HashEntry<HashedObj>> array;`

Comment: `_HASHTABLE_H` is a [reserved name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783). You should remove the leading underscore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HashEntry` itself is a template class, and doesn't automatically deduce the template parameter type from the containing `HashTable` class. You need to change the `array` declaration as follows

```
template <class HashedObj>
class HashTable {

private:
    std::vector<HashEntry<HashedObj>> array;
                      // ^^^^^^^^^^^
    // ...
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. std::vector<HashEntry<HashedObj>> array; is worked but without std it is not working. What is std:: for?

Comment: @bug `std::` specifies that `vector` is declared in the `std` namespace. You either have to specify it explicitly, or put a `using namespace std;` before using classes from that namespace (the latter isn't recommended in most cases though).